# passing keras TimeDistributed wrapper multiple inputs, only one with time dimension

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I'm brand new to Keras...  been reading the documentation...  referencing the last example ("Video Question Answering Model") in the Intro to Keras Functional API here:  https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/

In a nutshell, this example takes a natural language question about a video and does a softmax on possible answers.  Essentially a vision_model is developed to encode one frame of video.  It's wrapped with a TimeDistributed() and applied to a video sequence...  that's passed to an LSTM to get one vector for the whole video sequence...  and that's concatenated with an encoded question.

original code here:

```
video_input = Input(shape=(100, 3, 224, 224))
# This is our video encoded via the previously trained vision_model (weights are reused)
encoded_frame_sequence = TimeDistributed(vision_model)(video_input)  # the output will be a sequence of vectors
encoded_video = LSTM(256)(encoded_frame_sequence)  # the output will be a vector

# This is a model-level representation of the question encoder, reusing the same weights as before:
question_encoder = Model(inputs=question_input, outputs=encoded_question)

# Let's use it to encode the question:
video_question_input = Input(shape=(100,), dtype='int32')
encoded_video_question = question_encoder(video_question_input)

# And this is our video question answering model:
merged = keras.layers.concatenate([encoded_video, encoded_video_question])
output = Dense(1000, activation='softmax')(merged)
video_qa_model = Model(inputs=[video_input, video_question_input], outputs=output)
```

What if I wanted to throw out the LSTM on the video sequence and ask the same question about every frame, and do a softmax on potential outputs for all 100 frames?  I can conceptually think of two approaches, but I don't really know how to implement either, or if there's an entirely better approach for what seems like a common use case.

**Approach 1**

I suspect this is the way to go...  concatenate the encoded question with the output of vision_model, which is designed to encode one image...  this was done in the previous example at the same link ("Visual question answering model") and is called vqa_model.

```
vqa_model = Model(inputs=[image_input, question_input], outputs=output)
```

Now can I pass this to a TimeDistributed wrapper??

```
approach_1 = TimeDistributed(vqa_model)([video_input, question_input])
```

This yields an assertion error, for (I think) obvious reasons.

```
AssertionError
----> 1 approach_1 = TimeDistributed(vqa_model)([video_input, question_input])

Path\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    558                     self.build(input_shapes[0])
    559                 else:
--> 560                     self.build(input_shapes)
    561                 self.built = True
    562 

Path\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\wrappers.py in build(self, input_shape)
    139 
    140     def build(self, input_shape):
--> 141         assert len(input_shape) >= 3
    142         self.input_spec = InputSpec(shape=input_shape)
    143         child_input_shape = (input_shape[0],) + input_shape[2:]

AssertionError:
```

I need to pass it two inputs, only one of which (video_input) actually has the time dimension (question_input does not).  Is there a way to make something like this work...  or do I need to broadcast the embedded question 100x to match the time dimension of video input?  That seems awfully inefficient.

**Approach 2**

This idea seems super clunky...  but if I made vqa_model a shared layer, and manually called it 100x on the same question, but the next frame of video.

```
vqa_1 = vqa_model([frame_1, question_input])
vqa_2 = vqa_model([frame_2, question_input])
...
vqa_100 = vqa_model([frame_100, question_input])
```

or...  more likely...  am I going about this all wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I am also having the same problem... Did you happen to find a solution that you can share? Thanks!

Comment: nope.  i never did get this figured out.  I wish i had, but I dropped the problem that raised the issue temporarily and haven't had a chance to get back to it yet.  if you figure something out, I'd love to hear what you do!